# How to get SPARLQ's AKS answer if it returns true?

Tags: sparql

I'm a beginner in SPARQL and I'm trying to do some exercises. One of them is the following:

**Is your favorite actor / actress married?**

I'm using an ASK query:

```
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX dbr: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>

ASK
WHERE {dbr:Steve_Carell dbo:spouse ?any}
```

This query returns true.

My answer is: is there a way to return `?any` when the ASK query is true? In other words, is there the possibility to build an IF ... THEN cosntruct in SPARQL?

I tried with something like this:

```
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX dbr: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>

SELECT ?any {
ASK
WHERE {dbr:Steve_Carell dbo:spouse ?any}
}
```

but obviously it doesn't work.

Any hint?

Comment: the solution is to use either ASK or SELECT, in your case just SELECT

Answer (score 0):

`ASK` may be matching multiple items. If you just want one of them:

```
SELECT ?any {
   dbr:Steve_Carell dbo:spouse ?any
} LIMIT 1
```

which return one row with `?any` (i.e ASK = true) or no rows (ASK = false).

This can also be used as a sub-SELECT to get one of the possibilities (which it returns is not determined).